# The series $\sum_{n\geq 0}\exp(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}})-1$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n=\exp(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}})-1$. Then we have the following results:

1. $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{a_n}=0$
2. $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ so the ratio test is non conclusive
3. $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{(a_n)^{1/n}}=1$ so the root test is non conclusive as well

How to proceed to show that the series:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\exp\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)-1$$

diverges (as I checked with Wolfram Alpha)?

Comment: $\exp(x) - 1 \geqslant x$.

Comment: ah yes, than kyou Daniel!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $e^x \geqslant 1 + x$ (with equality only for $x = 0$), so

$$\exp \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}}\right)-1 > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$$

for $n \geqslant 1$, so we have the minorisation by the divergent series $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$, hence the series diverges.